# Dúvida com relação ao gerenciamento do JPA com Spring em servidor JEE

Tags: java, java-ee, spring, spring-mvc

Estou iniciando em Spring MVC e no livro que estou lendo a configuração e gerenciamento de conexões é toda feita pelo Spring, ou seja, o Spring abre e gerencia as conexões com o banco e disponibiliza isso como se eu tivesse em um servidor JEE (`@PersistenceContext` e `@Transactional`).

A questão é que isso tudo é feito em um web container como o tomcat ou jetty, minha duvida é como gerenciar essa questão em um servidor JEE completo como o Wildfly, pois quero que a conexão seja criada pelo Wildfly (*Datasource* criado no wildfly) e não pelo Spring

Como funciona essa integração, não faço nenhuma configuração de conexão do Spring e deixo apenas a cargo do servidor, ou tenho que configurar algo no Spring para que ele possa pegar o datasource criado pelo wildfly e ele (spring) fazer o gerenciamento?  Minha duvida é também pois existe um filtro do Spring que mantem as conexões abertas durante todo o request (`org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`) e como  ele vai gerenciar isso se as conexoes forem gerenciadas pelo servidor JEE (wildfly)?

Estou usando o Spring 4.2 e configurando tudo via annotations, segue trecho da configuração atual que funciona em um web container:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "br.com.casadocodigo.loja.models" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean   
    public DataSource dataSource(Environment environment){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.200:3306/casadocodigo");
        dataSource.setUsername( "root" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "123456" );
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);     
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

É possivel fazer o lookup do DataSource com JNDI.

Existe duas formas de fazer programaticamente.

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return lookup.getDataSource("jdni");
}
```

ou

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource ds = null;
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/nomeBanco");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Caso for utilizar o `JndiDataSourceLookup`, dá uma olhada no método `setResourceRef`, visto que o container é Java EE.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou perfeitamente! Com relação a setResourceRef estou colocando o prefixo, pelo menos por enquanto.

Answer (score 1):

Se o que o container está gerenciado para você é o *data source*, basta alterar a forma com que você recupera o *data source*.

Ao contrário de usar [`DriverManagerDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html), que é uma implementação básica de [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html), você pode recuperar o recurso pelo recurso JNDI publicado pelo container.

Partindo da sua configuração, basta alterar a implementação de `JPAConfiguration#dataSource` para algo como isto:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    final JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
    return jndi.lookup("${jndi.ds.name}", DataSource.class);
}
```

Ou assim:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws DataSourceLookupFailureException {
    return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("${jndi.ds.name}");
}
```

Esta segunda maneira é mais elegante, já que encapsula a [`JndiTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiTemplate.html) para você, além de fazer outras tratativas, como tentativa com outros endereços na JNDI.

Em XML ficaria algo como isto:

```xml
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="${jndi.ds.name}" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Vale ressaltar que o seu [`EntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) também pode ser gerenciado pelo container Java EE e não pelo Spring, substituindo o `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

Neste caso a configuração será um pouco diferente do comumente usado. Usando configuração em Java, seria algo assim:

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
    final JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
    return jndi.lookup("${jta.emf.jndi}", EntityManagerFactory.class);
}

@Bean
public TransactionFactory transactionManager(){
    return new JtaTransactionManager();
}
```

Em XML ficaria algo como isto:

```xml
<!-- referência da EMF na JNDI -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="${jta.emf.jndi}" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />

<!-- você deve falar que agora é JTA -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
```

Neste último caso pode ser necessário configuração adicional na unidade de persistência e pode quebrar a portabilidade *servlet container*/*full jee container*.

Quanto a questão do [`OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html) independe de como o spring consegue uma conexão ou se é ele quem gerencia as conexões, este filtro não tem conhecimento disto, bastando que exista um *bean* no contexto do Spring para a [`EntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) (nome padrão do *bean* é `entityManagerFactory`) - e este pode ser tanto gerenciado por ele quanto a recuperada da JNDI e gerenciada pelo container.

Última observação é que se você configura bem sua aplicação para rodar em um *servlet container* conseguirá também rodá-la sempre problema nenhum em um *jee container*.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionando perfeitamente no gerenciamento pelo Spring! Vou testar a abordagem do gerenciamento exclusivo pelo container para aprendizado.